# is it possible to run Drools rules dynamically?

Tags: java, drools

I have the following in my drl file

```
rule 1
  when
    ...
  then
    ...
end

rule 2
  when
    ...
  then
    ...
end

....

rule 40
  when
    ...
  then
    ...
end
```

What I am trying to do is to execute the rules in the order I want. for example
40 first then 39 second...and so on.
I read about salience but the value of salience is hard set. How am I able to achieve to read the rules whichever order I wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drools supports dynamic salience. You can define it based on any expression from the incoming data:

Check the [Role Attributes doc](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e3761)

But basically you can define a global variable (array or map)   that you inject in the context and then define the salience based on that. For instance:

```
rule 1
  salience( ruleOrders[1] )
  when
    ...
  then
    ...
end

rule 2
  salience( ruleOrders[2] )
  when
    ...
  then
    ...
end

....

rule 40
  salience( ruleOrders[40] )
  when
    ...
  then
    ...
end
```

You can also use bound variables if somehow you get the order of each rule from there:

```
rule 1
  salience( $order )
  when
    Element( $order : order )
  then
    ...
end
```

Comment: how do you define the ruleOrder? or how do you inject ruleOrder to drl rules

Comment: There's an example here: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e3299